# ¿Cómo seleccionar una columna de una tabla que contiene series temporales?

Tags: r, tablas

Tengo una tabla que la importo desde excel, en esta tabla  hay 50 variable macroeconómicas trimestrales. Consigue convertir cada columna de la tabla en una serie-temporal:

```
Data_timeseries=data_macro_trim
for (step in 1: (ncol(data_macro_trim)-1))
{Data_timeseries[,step+1]=ts(data_macro_trim[,step+1], start=c(2005, 1), end=c(2017, 2), frequency=4)}
```

Ahora las series trimestrales las quiero convertir en mensuales con el método de denton-cholette, pero no consigo seleccionar las columnas (que son series temporales) para poder utilizarlo

```
for (step in 1: (ncol(data_macro_trim)-1))
{Denton_cho_monthly[,step+1]=predict(td(Data_timeseries[,step+1]~ 1, to = "monthly", method = "denton-cholette"))}
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

> Error in td(Data_timeseries[, step + 1] ~ 1, to = "monthly", method =
>   "denton-cholette") :    the left hand side of the formula must be
>   either a time series or numeric.

¿Cómo seleccionaría la columna?

Muchas gracias

---

```
datos:> dput(Libro1)
structure(list(Date = c("Q1_2005", "Q2_2005", "Q3_2005", "Q4_2005", 
"Q1_2006", "Q2_2006", "Q3_2006", "Q4_2006", "Q1_2007", "Q2_2007", 
"Q3_2007", "Q4_2007", "Q1_2008", "Q2_2008", "Q3_2008", "Q4_2008", 
"Q1_2009", "Q2_2009", "Q3_2009", "Q4_2009", "Q1_2010", "Q2_2010"
), GDP_yoy = c(3.4559, 3.6985, 3.6494, 4.0814, 4.1608, 4.1845, 
4.2236, 4.1281, 4.0642, 3.8268, 3.6394, 3.5537, 2.9692, 2.1961, 
0.6142, -1.257, -3.2735, -4.2626, -3.8356, -2.9138, -1.0422, 
0.114), GDP__qoq = c(1.0092, 1.0189, 0.9522, 1.0401, 1.0863, 
1.0419, 0.9901, 0.9475, 1.0242, 0.8114, 0.8079, 0.864, 0.454, 
0.0545, -0.7525, -1.0119, -1.5974, -0.9687, -0.3098, -0.0631, 
0.2995, 0.1884), GDP_level = c(93.4519, 94.4041, 95.303, 96.2942, 
97.3402, 98.3544, 99.3282, 100.2693, 101.2963, 102.1182, 102.9432, 
103.8326, 104.304, 104.3608, 103.5755, 102.5274, 100.8896, 99.9123, 
99.6028, 99.54, 99.8381, 100.0262), Unemployment_a_p = c(10.17, 
9.32, 8.41, 8.71, 9.03, 8.44, 8.08, 8.26, 8.42, 7.93, 8.01, 8.57, 
9.6, 10.36, 11.23, 13.79, 17.24, 17.77, 17.75, 18.66, 19.84, 
19.89), CPI_yoy = c(3.26, 3.22, 3.44, 3.55, 4.02, 3.95, 3.53, 
2.59, 2.42, 2.39, 2.37, 3.96, 4.38, 4.6, 4.91, 2.45, 0.47, -0.68, 
-1.07, 0.14, 1.09, 1.59), CPI_qoq = c(-0.39, 2.27, 0.1, 1.55, 
0.05, 2.2, -0.29, 0.63, -0.11, 2.17, -0.32, 2.19, 0.29, 2.38, 
-0.03, -0.2, -1.65, 1.22, -0.42, 1.03, -0.72, 1.71), CPI_level = c(81.93, 
83.79, 83.88, 85.18, 85.22, 87.1, 86.84, 87.38, 87.29, 89.18, 
88.9, 90.84, 91.11, 93.28, 93.26, 93.07, 91.54, 92.65, 92.26, 
93.21, 92.54, 94.12), housing_prices_yoy = c(15.74, 13.91, 13.41, 
12.75, 12, 10.81, 9.83, 9.11, 7.24, 5.78, 5.34, 4.77, 3.81, 2.01, 
0.36, -3.21, -6.82, -8.34, -8.31, -6.25, -4.72, -3.75), housing_prices_qoq = c(4.17, 
4, 1.64, 2.4, 3.47, 2.9, 0.74, 1.73, 1.69, 1.5, 0.33, 1.18, 0.76, 
-0.27, -1.29, -2.43, -2.99, -1.9, -1.25, -0.24, -1.41, -0.9), 
    housing_prices_level = c(1685.4, 1752.8, 1781.5, 1824.3, 
    1887.6, 1942.3, 1956.7, 1990.5, 2024.2, 2054.5, 2061.2, 2085.5, 
    2101.4, 2095.7, 2068.7, 2018.5, 1958.1, 1920.9, 1896.8, 1892.3, 
    1865.7, 1848.9), `land_prices_(%_yoy)` = c(25.2336901244733, 
    12.4160777385159, 16.1976483022856, 8.06275524645181, -0.44862126310089, 
    1.53628541118229, 3.71423157096833, 6.49204864359214, 5.5825337010994, 
    8.58292701803267, 4.14763383884524, -2.65987350667606, -7.68268452424754, 
    -7.76193870277977, -9.8, -10.489838645634, -4.82263850139497, 
    -4.33505911444247, -7.54269265180689, -6.45239343468968, 
    -14.28391959799, -14.8949919224556), land_prices_qoq = c(4.5529901742752, 
    -1.57017442085315, 3.6697968645633, 1.2886109531931, -3.68194574368568, 
    0.392370148789856, 5.89350669452826, 4.0014617211767, -4.50456781447648, 
    3.2452719111046, 1.56806842480399, -2.79649122807019, -9.43219145940871, 
    3.15663611000399, -0.676145583803411, -3.53989185824872, 
    -3.69802798725651, 3.68509212730317, -4.00646203554119, -2.40238976775496, 
    -11.7601413975945, 2.94591821779275), land_prices_level = c(258.57, 
    254.51, 263.85, 267.25, 257.41, 258.42, 273.65, 284.6, 271.78, 
    280.6, 285, 277.03, 250.9, 258.82, 257.07, 247.97, 238.8, 
    247.6, 237.68, 231.97, 204.69, 210.72)), .Names = c("Date", 
"GDP_yoy", "GDP__qoq", "GDP_level", "Unemployment_a_p", "CPI_yoy", 
"CPI_qoq", "CPI_level", "housing_prices_yoy", "housing_prices_qoq", 
"housing_prices_level", "land_prices_(%_yoy)", "land_prices_qoq", 
"land_prices_level"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hola Anaa podrías incluir algún ejemplo de tus datos para poder reproducir tu ejemplo. Si no se pueden incluir los datos originales puedes incluir algunos simulados con la misma estructura.

Comment: El error lo que te está diciendo es que `Data_timeseries[,step+1]` no es una serie de tiempo, o al menos la función no lo interpreta como tal. ¿Podrías verificarlo con `is.ts(Data_timeseries[,step+1])`? O como ya te dijeron, compartir una muestra de los datos con `dput(data_macro_trim)`.

Comment: Efectivamente no interpreta que sea una serie temporal. Añado una pequeña extracción de mi base de

Answer (score 0):

#### Problema:

Entiendo que está en la construcción inicial de la serie de tiempos. Probando con el ejemplo de los datos que has dado:

```
data_macro_trim <- Libro1
Data_timeseries=data_macro_trim
for (step in 1: (ncol(data_macro_trim)-1))
{Data_timeseries[,step+1]=ts(data_macro_trim[,step+1], start=c(2005, 1), end=c(2017, 2), frequency=4)}
```

Obtenemos un error:

> ```
> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , step + 1, value = c(3.4559, 3.6985,  : 
>   replacement has 50 rows, data has 22
> ```

Claro, estamos generando una nueva serie de tiempo que tendría 50 filas y tratándola de asignar al `data.frame` ya existente que solo tiene 22. Si seguimos con el código y aplicamos la desagregación temporal obtendremos el error que has informado en tu pregunta, simplemente por que no hemos conseguido generar las series de tiempo aún.

#### Solución:

Para generar las series de tiempo nos conviene construir un nuevo objeto:

```
data_macro_trim <- Libro1
Data_timeseries <- data.frame(lapply(2:ncol(data_macro_trim),function(x) {ts(data_macro_trim[,x], start=c(2005, 1), end=c(2017, 2), frequency=4)}))
names(Data_timeseries) <- names(data_macro_trim)[-1]
```

Es más compacto y performante usar `lapply()` que el ciclo `for` y al ser el retorno de esta función una lista, es gratis convertir la misma en un `data.frame`.

La lógica es sencilla:

- por cada columna de `data_macro_trim` menos la primera (`2:ncol(data_macro_trim)`) aplicaremos una función que es la generación de la serie de tiempo (`function(x) {ts(data_macro_trim[,x], start=c(2005, 1), end=c(2017, 2), frequency=4)}`).
- Por último renombramos las columnas por los nombres originales: `names(Data_timeseries) <- names(data_macro_trim)[-1]`

Por último, la desagregación temporal mediante `ts()` la aplicamos de una forma similar.

```
new_Data_timeseries <- data.frame(lapply(1:ncol(Data_timeseries),function(x) {predict(td(Data_timeseries[,x] ~ 1, to = "monthly", method = "denton-cholette"))}))
names(new_Data_timeseries) <- names(Data_timeseries)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Patricio. He probado el código pero me sigue dando error, creo que me sigue diciendo que no es una serie temporal:  Error in td(Data_timeseries[, x] ~ 1, to = "monthly", method = "denton-cholette") : 
  In non-ts mode, 'to' must be an integer number.

Comment: @Anaa, los datos que compartiste entiendo que no son los reales no? por que con los mismos lo he probado y el código funciona como se espera. Revisa cada una de las columnas, al menos agrega a tu pregunta la estructura de la base mediante `str(data_macro_trim)`. Estas convirtiendo desde la columna 1 hasta la anteúltima, todas tienen datos válidos para convertir  a un `ts`?